# Advice on the use of pointers/references when passing arguments to C++ routines

Tags: c++, reference

I work with C++ in an embedded environment (actually a subset of C++) and want some advice on the use of pointers/references when passing arguments to routines.

A common tip goes something like "use references when you can, and pointers when you have to". I believe this is related to avoiding null pointers.

However, our current programming guideline prohibits the use of references.

Please refer to the discussion thread below, and see if you agree.

Bert:
We should be taking advantage of passing arguments by reference (built-in null pointer protection) when appropriate. This would yield smaller, more robust code.

Ernie:
I disagree.  Using references hides what parameters might be changed and as such, when you are reviewing code or looking at what a particular function is doing, you now have to look at each and every function it calls, and each and every function they call to see if any of the parameters you are passing in might get changed.
Whereas, if you use pointers, then you know by the fact that if you are passing in a pointer, it might get changed.  If you are not passing in a pointer, then you know it has not been changed.
This ease in maintenance is worth the NULL pointer issues.  With references, just because you don't have NULL pointer issues, does not mean that the object has been correctly initialized and that you have good data.

Bert:
That concern can be mitigated by labeling input parameters (references) as "const".  (This is similar to the Google coding style.) Then you know the other parameters are the ones that may be modified. The modifiable parameters can start with the "r" prefix, which was allowed in our guidelines earlier. (And don't be surprised when tools such as Visual Assist color code inputs/outputs to help give visual cues.)

Ernie:
Labeling parameter (references) as "const" does NOT mitigate the problem.  Because when you are up a level and someone is calling the function, then you have just a regular variable like "nSomeNumber".  You MUST go to the function prototype to see if that variable might get changed.  Or, you MUST hover over the function to see the prototype.  So you can not just quickly scan code and have an idea of what might be happening.
Also, there are times where you do not have color coding, like in Beyond Compare during a code review, and you can not easily hover or go to the prototype.
I am strongly against the use of references, as they make code maintenance and readability difficult and error prone; and the errors you get are not the simple to detect NULL pointer issues, they are logic errors where a value is set above a function and passed into the function as a reference, and then after the function is called the value is used and not having expected it to change.

Grover:
FYI, Google allows const reference for arguments.  Presumably, this is to save on the cost of copying objects. Google does not allow simple reference for arguments.  If an object is to change, then pass it by pointer.
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Arguments

Comment: tl;dr Is there an actual question?

Comment: I've never understood this argument about not knowing if an argument might be modified.  Are people just passing their objects to random functions without knowing what the functions are supposed to do?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: In a big codebase any particular coder may not what what every call does, so when reading a piece of code you don't work on regularly you may not know which parameters are IN, which are OUT and which are IN/OUT. Not, that I agree with this argument--I'd rather check with the documentation when needed--but it is an issue. More for maintenance that for writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A common tip goes something like "use references when you can, and pointers when you have to". I believe this is related to avoiding null pointers.

This is good advice, and yes, avoiding null pointers is the reason (it's also easier to read as you don't have to constantly dereference references, or use `->`)

> Grover: FYI, Google allows const reference for arguments. Presumably, this is to save on the cost of copying objects. Google does not allow simple reference for arguments. If an object is to change, then pass it by pointer.

I can understand the argument against using non-const references. In that case, Google's style guide is the best approach (use const references for inputs, pointers for outputs). Not using const references for inputs is just madness: you either have to pass by value, which will be incredibly slow, or pass by pointer, which is going to require a hell of a lot of address taking and dereferencing (not to mention pointless null pointer checks). *That* would make the code far more unreadable than worrying about modified references.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd suggest is that references be always `const` (like in Google style) *unless* it is obvious from the function's task that an argument might end up modified inside the function. This should, IMO, happen only when all other ways are much less readable, i.e. you should generally try to keep functions as 'functional' as possible, taking const arguments and returning something else. Depending on how big this subset of C++ is, that should not be a problem: mutable state information you might be tempted to change in a function `f` can almost always be organized in a way so that this information resides in a class `c` which `f` is a member of, and then you can further seperate apart 'modifying functions' and 'pure functions', so that your functions are in the end mostly of either of the forms

```
class c;

ret_T f0(const arg1T &, const arg2T &, ...);
ret_T c::f1(const arg1T &, const arg2T &, ...) const;  // pure functions

void c::f3(const arg1T &, const arg2T &, ...);       // modifying functions
c &c::f2(const arg1T &, const arg2T &, ...){
   ...  return *this;
}
```

Obviously, that's not always possible or at least not always feasible, but it *is* often enough so that it won't hurt to give those functions that don't fit in this schema (i.e. functions that return something nontrivial *and* modify the state) nice long descriptive names to make it clear that they will.